# I am getting this error when I run the code mentioned below

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, visual-studio, kivy

I am getting the mentioned error when I run this code.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGridLayout(GridLayout):
    # Initialize infinite keywords
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # call grid layout customer
        super(MyGridLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # Set columns
        self.cols = 2
        # Add widgets
        self.add_widget(Label(text="Name: "))
        # add input box
        self.name = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget = self.name
        # Add widget
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Last Name"))
        #add input box
        self.lname = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget = self.lname
        # Add widget
        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Contact"))
        #add input box
        self.contact = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget = self.contact

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGridLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

I am getting this error when I run the code mentioned below.

```
>           *MyApp().run()
>            File "C:\Kivy\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
>              self._run_prepare()
>            File "C:\Kivy\virt\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
>              root = self.build()
>            File "C:\Kivy\second.py", line 33, in build
>              return MyGridLayout()
>            File "C:\Kivy\second.py", line 21, in __init__
>              self.add_widget(Label(text = "Last Name"))
>          TypeError: 'TextInput' object is not callable
```

Comment: ***import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button***
 
This is mentioned in the code as headers

Comment: Drop the `self.add_widget = self.name` line.

Answer (score 0):

In every case where you have:

```
self.add_widget =
```

it is an error. Replace each of those with a correct call to `self.add_widget()`. For example, replace:

```
self.add_widget = self.contact
```

with:

```
self.add_widget(self.contact)
```

and similarly in two other places.